# Laragon never use mysql password

Tags: laragon

I try to use Laragon but when i try to create a new Laravel project, Laragon try to create the DB without using a password.

I have this error : 
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

How to define the password to Laragon ? 
Ty for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to my.ini and in the first line configure your password.

Answer (score 10):

In Laragon's **Menu > MySQL**, you can:
- Change your root password.
- Reset your root password.

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your replie. But i try this and there is an error and laragon ask me to reset the password...

Comment: To precise, this is the error : `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Done, i didn't see but i had to define my password in my.ini... Thank's for your time !

Comment: I started Laragon as an administrator and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I already had mySQL all setup on my PC

I went to MySQL -> my.ini this opened the my.ini file in a editor

[image]

I then entered mySQL password which I have already had.  Saved the file and Laragon used this password successfully

[image]

Comment: Although I had used the commend: "mysql_secure_installation" and had set a password for the user: "root", Laragon had not changed the password field in the "my.ini" file. Thanks a million for the hints you provided.

Comment: That doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just log in to the database and run this command

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpassword');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Like so:

1. Click on the *Database* button in the Dashboard.
2. Open the default connection (no password). This will open HeidiSQL.
3. In the *Query* tab enter the command above and execute it.
4. Reconnect.

Comment: I tried the ini trick and am clearly missing something because it no worky worky. This worked verbatim. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem ,  and none of the above suggestion would work

the only thing i resolved this issue by
**Running Laragon as the administrator**
and then

In Laragon's Menu > MySQL, you can:

- Change your root password.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press win key + R
2. write services.msc
3. Stop MySql
4. Run laragon from adminstrator.
5. Menu ---> MySQL---> Change root password

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to phpmyadmin, then go to 'User Accounts' tab. Then on the 'root' clikc on 'Edit privileges' and 'Change Password'

[change root password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGwhJ.png)